# ffmpeg crashes with "Internal bug", "Failed to inject frame into filter network" while trying to convert PNG files into an animated gif using filters

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, png, animated-gif, color-palette

ffmpeg version: ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1

Kernel: 5.4.0-122-lowlatency #138-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

PNG-Images: 996 pieces, all equal in size: 1000x50

Then trying to build palette using palettegen:

```
export filters="scale=1000:-1:flags=lanczos"
export palette=./stripes_palette.png
ffmpeg -v warning -i ./palette_source_stripes.png -vf "$filters,palettegen=stats_mode=diff" -y $palette
[Parsed_palettegen_1 @ 0x55f0eea30e00] Dupped color: FF63000D
```

Palette file has been created, looks good so far. Then I tried to convert all 996 PNG files into one single (space optimized) animated GIF file using paletteuse:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -framerate 5 -thread_queue_size 2048 -i ./tmp/temp.%04d.png -i $palette -lavfi "$filters,paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=5:diff_mode=rectangle" -r 5 -loop -1 -y testanim.gif
Error while filtering: Internal bug, should not have happened
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Internal bug, should not have happened
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

The reason for "-framerate 5" for the input and "-r 5" for the output is: I wanted the animated GIF to use a determined time for running through animation. It already had worked out without using complex filtering, but the results were huge GIF files which are hard to handle.
But even when I avoid both framerate parameters, still the same error message occurs.

Should I look deeper into the "Dupped color" which has been mentioned? Did anybody encounter a similar issue using ffmpeg?
I'm not used to deal with filters (nor "complex filters") in ffmpeg, I'm very new at this, but I've found no tips regarding an ffmpeg crash like I've right here.

------------------------------- EDIT 2022-08-12/1 ---------------------

Same error occurs with current stable version
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

------------------------------- EDIT 2022-08-12/2 ---------------------

Found workaround, see answer below

Comment: Can't help you with the bug, but you're using really old version of FFmpeg. Consider getting the latest version. Maybe the bug has been resolved since v4.2.7

Comment: Well, that's the version my unbuntu is offering. But, yes, I will try to go for a current version. That will take some time anyway. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: 4.2.7 is the current version for ubuntu "Focal Fossa" (20.04.4 LTS). Maybe I could create a virtual machine to test a most recent version dealing with my code snippets

Comment: Tested also on v4.2.2 (official latest stable release), result: Negative

ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

Error while filtering: Internal bug, should not have happened
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Internal bug, should not have happened
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

Answer (score 1):

At first glance: This workaround does not solve the problem, but I lets me produce my animated GIF files in high quality and small size (50kB approx). Why ffmpeg crashes when trying to convert multiple PNG files directly into one animated GIF? Who knows. But now let's proceed to the workaround I've found:

- Source: 996 PNG files, all 1000x50 pixels in size
- Goal: Similar animated GIF files in high quality, small size and different speeds

The idea: First, lets convert all PNG files into one lossless video file, then convert this video file into different GIF files.

1. Create ffmpeg filter for later use:

```
export filters="scale=1000:-1:flags=lanczos"
export palette=/tmp/ffmpeg_gif_palette.png
ffmpeg -v warning -i $OD/$TF.0000.png -vf "$filters,palettegen=stats_mode=diff" -y $palette
```

2. Convert PNG files into one monolithic AVI file:

```
ffmpeg -i $OD/$TF.%04d.png -c:v ffv1 -qscale:v 0 $OD/lossless_temp.avi
```

3. Within a loop, convert AVI file to animated GIF with specific framerate:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -r $fr -thread_queue_size 2048 -i $OD/lossless_temp.avi -i $palette -lavfi "$filters,paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=5:diff_mode=rectangle" -r $fr -loop -1 -y $OFA.$secstr.gif
```

And, yes, this has worked out, animated gifs have been produced:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 57152 Aug 12 22:44 erg_animated.030.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 57152 Aug 12 22:44 erg_animated.060.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 57152 Aug 12 22:44 erg_animated.090.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 57152 Aug 12 22:44 erg_animated.120.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 57152 Aug 12 22:44 erg_animated.150.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 57152 Aug 12 22:44 erg_animated.180.gif
```